Generate "fromCode" method with lombok
I started using lombok recently, it's great to get rid of pesky boiler code.
When working with Enums, one kind of code I'm used to write over and over again is "fromCode" methods, that return the enum value corresponding to a code passed in a constructor.
E.g.
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum FOO {
   ALICE("A"),BOB("B");

   private code;

   public static FOO fromCode(String code){
      for(FOO v: FOO.values()){
         if(v.code.equals(code)){
             return v;
         }
      }
      return null;
   }
}

Are there really no annotations allowing to generate that kind of code ? Am I really forced to copy paste that kind of code in all my Enums ?
BONUS Question.
I often use "code" to map to my enums the value they take in DB. (when the enum entry itself is too long).
So if it would also be possible to generate an @AttributeConverter, that would be great
Something like :
@AllArgsConstructor
@MagicEnumConverterAnnotation
public enum FOO {
   ALICE("A"),BOB("B");

   private code;

  
}

instead of :
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum FOO {
   ALICE("A"),BOB("B");

   private code;

   public static FOO fromCode(String code){
      for(FOO v: FOO.values()){
         if(v.code.equals(code)){
             return v;
         }
      }
      return null;
   }
}

public static class Converter implements AttributeConverter<FOO, String> {

        @Override
        public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Foo t) {
            return t.code;
        }

        @Override
        public FOO convertToEntityAttribute(String t) {
            return FOO.fromCode(t);
        }
    }



There have been a few discussions on this topic on the lombok mailing list and in some GitHub issues. It seems the maintainers like the idea, but it's not that simple.

Do you know if they gave up the idea or if they are still trying to figure it out ?

I think it was just lost in between all those other tasks that the maintainers have to do. And probably a lack of effort from contributors.
